# Remove cell border spacing from selected rows

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to remove the border spacing between the selected rows/cells? i want to remove the spacing between the "content" cells and show it as one row.  i tried to add the `border-spacing` for the selected rows but it doesn't seem to be working

Below is my code

```
<html>
<head>
   
    <style>
    
        .flex_container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .inner {
            height:1000px;
            width: 900px;

            background-color:#000;
            
            background-size: cover;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
           /* justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            */
        }
        
        .table-border {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 6px 5px;
  table-layout: fixed;

  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;

}

.table-border tr th {
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255,0.6);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.content-inner {
margin-top: 250px;
margin-left: 50px;
}
      
     
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex_container">
     <div class="inner">
        <div class="content-inner">
       <table class="table-border">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th>heading 1</th>
            <th>heading 2</th>
            <th>heading 3</th>
            <th>heading 4</th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)">
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Why did you set `border-spacing: 6px 5px;` than?

Comment: What means *"selected rows/cells"*?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i want the spacing only for the table heading

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan so the net row with the "content" should not have the spacing

Comment: You could make use of the `<thead>` tag :)

Comment: PS **never** style `TR` elements

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
   
    <style>
    
        .flex_container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .inner {
            height:1000px;
            width: 900px;

            background-color:#000;
            
            background-size: cover;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
           /* justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            */
        }
        
        .table-border {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  table-layout: fixed;

  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;

}

      
.table-border tr th {
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255,0.6);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;  
  border: 5px solid black;
}
.content-inner {
margin-top: 250px;
margin-left: 50px;
}
      
     
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex_container">
     <div class="inner">
        <div class="content-inner">
       <table class="table-border">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th>heading 1</th>
            <th>heading 2</th>
            <th>heading 3</th>
            <th>heading 4</th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)">
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

- Use `border-collapse: collapse;`
- Use `<thead>` and `<div>`s inside your `<th>` elements
- Finally, set margin to your DIV elements in TH

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}

.table-border {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.table-border thead th div {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0.8rem 1.4rem;
  margin: 0.3rem;
}

.table-border tbody td {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<table class="table-border">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>Heading 1</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>Heading 2</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>Heading 3</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>Heading 4</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You don't necessarily need `<table>` You can achieve something similar using regular DIVs, CSS flex or Grid, and the [aria-role="table"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Table_Role)